# SQL: Max of summed list from subgroup

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I've been looking around for a solution for this, and found many questions about finding a max of a summed group, but none of them solving my problem, hence I decided to make a new question.

My data is grouped in 3 levels and data would be like this:

```
+--------+---------+----+
| Sektor | Sektion | n  |
+--------+---------+----+
| 1      | a       | 9  |
| 1      | b       | 14 |
| 1      | a       | 6  |
| 2      | d       | 4  |
| 2      | d       | 7  |
| 2      | f       | 10 | 
| 2      | e       | 100|
| 3      | g       | 59 |
| 4      | h       | 200|
+--------+---------+----+
```

I would like to find the "sektion" with highest summed n for each "sektor".

I tried some different approaches, but none of them solved my problem. The closest i got was:

```
select
  sektor, sektion, n
from
  table
where
  n = (select max(n) from  table i where i.sektor =  table.sektor)
GROUP BY sektor, sektion, n
ORDER BY n DESC
```

This would return

```
+--------+---------+----+
| Sektor | Sektion | n  |
+--------+---------+----+
| 1      | b       | 14 |
| 2      | e       | 100|
| 3      | g       | 59 |
| 4      | h       | 200|
+--------+---------+----+
```

The problem is i don't get the max(n) for each group, but single instance. Sektor 1 should return sektion a with 15 instead.

Am i close to the answer, or far away? Seems like i just need to sum before taking the max, but not sure how.

Desired:

```
+--------+---------+----+
| Sektor | Sektion | n  |
+--------+---------+----+
| 1      | a       | 15 |
| 2      | e       | 100|
| 3      | g       | 59 |
| 4      | h       | 200|
+--------+---------+----+
```

Comment: I've re-read this question and it doesn't make sense. You say "a" should be displayed with 15 but that is not in your table that you've shown at the top.

Comment: Because "a" is twice with 9 and 6, and I would like the max of summed n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below, this works for me

```
Select Distinct
  sektor, Sektion, n
from
  table t
where
    n = (select max(n) from table where Sektor = t.Sektor)
```

Looking at your question again, it looks like all you were missing was a group by in your subquery

Also as your comment suggests that you want the max based on the sum, you may find this works for that scenario:

```
Select Sektor, Sektion, SUM(n) n
from Table t
Group by Sektor, Sektion
Having Sum(n) = (Select max(n) from (Select SUM(n) n from Table where Sektor = t.Sektor group by Sektion) a)
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions involved? Use DISTINCT instead in cases like this - if needed!

Comment: Great! You can also remove the GROUP BY from the sub-query, makes no difference since it's always the same sektor value (=t.sektor).

Comment: Doh! Forgot I had that one in there. Updated!